# PixelSearch&Mouse control

Tags: autohotkey, helper, minecraft-forge

## I am writing a small assistant bot for one minecraft server, you need to add a pixel search to the script and turn the camera left or right, depending on where the necessary block (snow block) is located

Here is the finished code:

```
f10::
MsgBox, 4096, AHK хелпер снегокопалка, Нажми ОК для того что бы начать автоматическую работу.
sleep 900
     loop{
    send, {click down}
    sleep 300
    send, {w down}
    sleep 700
    }
     return

; Пауза скрипта
f9:: 
MsgBox, 20496, Завершение скрипта, Вы нажали хоткей который завершает`nработу скрипта, по этому он будет остановлен.
Pause, Toggle

; Снятие с паузы
f8:: 
MsgBox, 20528, Снятие с паузы, Вы сняли скрипт с паузы,` после того как нажмёте ОК, сприпт возобновит свою работу.
Pause, Toggle
```

I tried to use tips from the official documentation on AK, as well as from the version translated into my language, and also used tips and ready-made solutions from other forums, but everything was even because either one of my lines of bot functionality fell off, or it was impossible to restart\ open the script itself, and also I didn't understand how to add the camera rotation function to the required block.